# How to extract substring from string with know prefix and suffix using Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

The string look likes

```
string1="userbasedn:DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com?subtree?(&(objectcategory=person)(uidNumber=*)(|(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com)(memberOf:1.2.840.11.1.4.1941:=cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com)))
groupbasedn:DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com?subtree?(&(objectcategory=group)(gidNumber=*))"
```

How to extract substring and adding to array like

```
arr[0]="cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com"
arr[1]="cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com"
```

From "cn" to "DC=com"

My approach to find substring

```
re='(^|cn)([^DC=com])(.*)'
remaining=$string1
while [[ $remaining =~ $re ]];
do
...

done
```

I am using Regex but can't find the proper combination of Posix Character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(grep -oE 'cn=[^()]*DC=com' <<< "$string1")

# check array content
declare -p arr

# or using printf
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

```
declare -a arr=([0]="cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com" [1]="cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com")

cn=example1,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com
cn=example2,OU=GROUPS,OU=INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=companyname,DC=com
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/XToe9a)